# How to ensure date entered into TcxDateEdit is within MinDate/MaxDate?

Tags: delphi, validation, date, devexpress

TcxDateEdit allows to set properties for `MinDate` and `MaxDate`. However I can't find a key that would make the control to validate the entered date automatically and ensure that the date is within the specified range.

For example:

```
MinDate := EncodeDate(1900, 1, 1);
MaxDate := EncodeDate(2100, 1, 1);
```

When I enter a date `1.1.1111` it throws an error instead of fitting it into the range `01.01.1900 .. 01.01.2100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code in `Properties.OnValidate` does the job:

```
procedure TForm.deDatePropertiesValidate(Sender: TObject; var DisplayValue: Variant; var ErrorText: TCaption; var Error: Boolean);
var
  ed: TcxDateEdit; //So we can use single handler for different controls
  dt: TDateTime;
begin
  ed := TcxDateEdit(Sender); 
  dt := StrToDateDef(DisplayValue, ed.Properties.MinDate);

  if not InRange(dt, ed.Properties.MinDate, ed.Properties.MaxDate) then
  begin
    DisplayValue := EnsureRange(dt, ed.Properties.MinDate, ed.Properties.MaxDate);
    ed.EditValue := DisplayValue;
  end;

  Error := False;
  ErrorText := '';
end;
```